# How can i rotate a text created by drawTextOnPath in circle path

Tags: android, android-canvas

cant figure it out how to rotate the text so the starting position isn't somewhere random. 
(I dont want to animate it). i just want to specify the starting position.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GraphicsView(this));
}

private static class GraphicsView extends View {
    private static final String QUOTE = "Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain.";
    Path circle;
    Paint tPaint;

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        tPaint = new Paint();
        tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        tPaint.setTextSize(30);
        tPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        //setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        circle = new Path();
        int centerX = getWidth()/2;
        int centerY = getHeight()/2; 
        circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, Math.min(centerX, centerY), Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 0, 30, tPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the `hOffset`-parameter according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawTextOnPath%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)?

> *hOffset*     The distance along the path to add to the text's starting
>   position

Comment: i did tried changing the hOffset and at first it seemed that it worked, but if u try that example urself u will see that if hOffset = 700 which is the position i want the text to start, the end of the text is missing.

Answer (score 5):

The displacement around the circle is based on the circumference being 2*pi radians.
So half way(180) is 1*Math.PI*radius and to start at the top(12 o'clock) is 1.5*Math.PI*radius.  The hOffset must be positive.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    circle = new Path();
    int centerX = getWidth()/2;
    int centerY = getHeight()/2;
    int radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY);
    circle.addCircle(centerX, centerY, Math.min(centerX, centerY), Direction.CW);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(QUOTE, circle, 1.5f*Math.PI*radius, 30, tPaint);
}
```